# Initializing Class members with zero

Tags: c++

I have a class in my code that has some integer data members but no methods. Is there exist a way to initialize all the data items with 0 when I create a new object of it using new()?

Comment: Add a constructor to the class/struct?

Comment: Constructor initializer list?

Comment: `class Foo { int i; Foo() : i(0) {} };`

Comment: I just want to make it clear that you don't have to use `new` to create a new object. `ClassName objectName;` works better in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, hmjd, jrok and chris. I'll add a constructor.

Comment: what about this?
class clasName{
 int x1= 0;
 int x2= 0;
 int x3= 0;
 int x4= 0;
 int x5= 0;
}

Comment: @Dipak, Works great, but only in C++11.

Comment: I don't think any compiler supports that syntax yet.

Comment: @chris : Thanks. I want this object to be allocated from heap.

Comment: @jrok, I know GCC does. I don't think the other two do. MSVC definitely doesn't.

Comment: @NeonGlow, Then I suggest a smart pointer.

Comment: @chris Cool, then it's about time I update.

Comment: @jrok, Ah, Clang does as well, since 3.0. I saw that talk about Clang that was posted recently, but I guess I got mixed up and thought it wan't.

Comment: I am working with GCC and target is MIPS32. So hopefully dipaks method will work. I'll check and update.

Comment: Dipaks method is giving me an error "ISO C++ forbids initializtion of member".

Comment: Try with `-std=c++0x` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class A
{
    int x_; 
    int y_; 

    public: 
        A() 
           : 
             x_(0),
             y_(0)
        {} 
};
```

The part of the A() constructor before the brackets "{}" is called an "initializer list", which you use to initialize the variables to a default value 0 in the case above, or to some other values that may be passed to a constructor that might take those values as arguments. However you initialize an object of type A (e.g. with "new"), the attributes will be initialized to those values. It is good coding style to initialize the attributes in the same order they are declared, it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Not only that, they get initialized in the order they're declared in the class. `: y_(0), x_(y)` is a bad thing to do, since `x` won't be initialized properly.

Comment: @chris: I know, but on some compilers without compiler options that output all warnings set on, not even a warning is produced during compilation, so it's good to point out that the initialization order should follow the order in which the attributes are declared..

Comment: I got a warning [GCC], when I tried to initialize in reverse order.

Comment: @NeonGlow I just re-run g++, without compiler flags, and with the compiler "g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3" and compiling the code with reversed intialization doesn't give me any warnings...

Comment: @tomislav-maric : It was not an error. Just a warning. Says "x and y will be re-ordered to match declaration order"

Comment: @NeonGlow, I didn't write error, I'm also talking about warnings... :) What compiler are you using, did you set any compiler flags? Like, if I use "g++ -Wall", then I get that warning as well, but if I only use g++, I don't get it.

Comment: @tomislav-maric : Mine is  "(GCC) 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7)". i think the strict checking is enabled.

Comment: @NeonGlow, this is a learning example and yet different compilers show different output.. it's interesting :)

Answer (score 3):

Value initialization:

```
struct X
{
    int i, j;
};

X* x = new X(); // The '()' are required.
// 0 == x->i && 0 == x->j
```

Comment: Are suggesting to update each member individually? My struct has a lot of members which makes it difficult. :(

Comment: @NeonGlow, It will value-initialize everything, which means `int` etc. will be initialized as well, not just the non-trivially-constructible types that would in default-initialization. If you want to see what happens in detail, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) is a good read.

Comment: @NeonGlow, no. The comment in the code snippet is expressing the result of the value initialization.

Answer (score 2):

```
class clasName{
 int x1= 0;
 int x2= 0;
 int x3= 0;
 int x4= 0;
 int x5= 0;
}
```

Only in C++11.

Comment: @Dipak : Flagging an error "ISO C++ forbids
   initialization of member" : gcc (GCC) 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7)

Comment: Now you messed up the answer completely - you're doing assignment of member. You better roll back the edit and read up some more about the topic.

Comment: @jrok : edit it or post your comment as answer. and close this question. :)

Comment: @NeonGlow : "ISO C++ forbids initialization of member" is just against convention not error?

Comment: @NeonGlow : what about assigning value to class variable from it constructor?

Comment: @Dipak : Yes it will be fine. I think the initializer list option is equally good.